# DNN module sugestions needed, form/reg, pyment, emailing

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

i need a module that is kind of a cross between a registration module and a form module.

it need to allow for custom form fields to be saved to the DB and work as part of a flow such that once data is entered by the users they click next and see the data to confirm it is correct. at this point they should have the option to edit the data if they notice an error or continue to a payment page.

the payment page needs to have a module that can integrat with payment gateways liek paypal and accept credit cards. once credit card data is entered and the transaction is complete a custom email with a unique userNumber needs to be sent to the user.

i figure im lookign at three separate modules for this typeof work flow. but i hope since this is a standard type of register, pay, email confirm operation there may be a single module i can confugure to meet my needs.

thoughts? suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at DNM RAD by DotNet Mushroom?

http://www.dotnetmushroom.com/DNMRADGeneral/GeneralInformation/WhatisDNMRAD/tabid/2347/Default.aspx

I have not had a use for this yet, but it is a module that I have on my short list in case the need comes up.  They do state that they can work with pament gateways.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to be somewhat flexible with your work flow if you want to used 100% canned modules.

> FormMaster is a pretty good form solution. You can write to existing database tables, structure SQL tables or just the default is an XML file.  It doesn't go through a preview before saving though.
>   [FormMaster Website](http://www.code5systems.com/Modules/FormMaster2008.aspx)
>
> Searching snowcovered.com you can certainly find something that can process a payment. That one shouldn't be too difficult.

I'm thinking you may need to sling some code to get the exact experience you are looking for.